# How to efficient extract new polygons form the exist polygons

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, polygon, graph-algorithm

the polygons image 
[image]

All of the polygons are simply, there are no holes in them.
  board polygon(P0 to P7)

Red polygon (R0 to  R6)

Green polygon (G0 G1 P2 G3)

Yellow polygon(Y0  to  Y3)

I want to got new four polygons marked as 1 to 4 , polygon 1's coordinates are(J7 J10 R5 R4).
 When I use polygon clipping algorithm, I can got the results easy , board diff(red union green union yellow). But when I have more than 10,000 polygons, I need a long time to get my results. My polygons are simply and my result polygons are simply also, there are no holes in the result polygons also.

You know I can find out the four polygons form the image easy using eyes, but how to find them using algorithm. 
Thanks.

Comment: It is nice that you want something. But have you shown any attempt at solving it? Otherwise, it looks like you are just looking for a code factory.

Answer (score 1):

If all vertices of your computed black polygons do not have more than 2 edges intersecting at the vertex, then there may be a faster way than a more general tool.

Since the number of polygons is on the order of 10000, first try computing the intersection points of all pairs of polygons, and hopefully the number of intersection points is small enough (like 10 million or less).  Then, for each intersection point test to see if it is contained in the interior of another polygon (in case you have multiple polygons that jointly overlap).  Testing to see if a point is contained in the interior of a polygon can be done quickly, you can read how online.  Then, all intersection points that are not contained in another polygon, which note also contains all the original polygon vertices that are not contained in the interior of a polygon, these are the vertices for the "black" polygons you want to compute.  These points should be stored with a secondary structure that for each polygon edge, it stores all the stored intersection points along that edge, in sorted order.  Similarly, for each stored vertex and intersection point you should store the edges that intersect at that point, and the location of the intersection point in the previous structure.  So then pick any stored intersection point that hasn't been used yet in a black polygon, and pick one edge that defines the intersection point.  Then you move to the neighboring intersection point along the edge which has the property that the part of the edge between the two intersection points does not pass inside a polygon.  Then continue by similarly moving along the other edge that defines the neighboring intersection point.  Continue until you reach the vertex you started at; this defines one black polygon.  Then you can pick a new unused stored intersection point and repeat.  Since your polygons have no holes, this will find all black polygons.